# Spring-Social-facebook + Spring MVC integration

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to access facebook data via spring social facebook integration using the instructions provided at http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook.

But currently i am facing 2 type of problem

1. When i run example as mentioned in tutorial i get following error

   No matching bean of type [org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook] found for dependency
2. When i run this with @Configuration on FacebookConfig class, i get below mentioned error

   A ConnectionFactory for provider 'facebook' has already been registered

Is there a workaround to it?

I have kept the war file with source code at https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EA49CD7184E0E40!168&authkey=!AIkoKKx5-Um8AQE

Comment: Please post your configuration along with each stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using?

Try using the version 1.1.0.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If it not works, please try post the stacktrace printed.

You need to create a the beans to your class, please post more information like your pom.xml and your spring context configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ihad the same problem. Spring Social Facebook will automatically add connection factory based on the configuration in application.properties. This auto-configured connection factory is clashing with the one that you're trying to add. Try just to remove your connection factory you add through addConnectionFactories.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different setting to load your custom connection factory...

E.g. Instead of using OOTB keys use different keys:

```
#Facebook Social App Details:
# Commented below 2 OOTB Keys & Bingo it worked.
#spring.social.facebook.appId=APP_ID
#spring.social.facebook.appSecret=APP_SECRET
facebook.app.id=APP_ID
facebook.app.secret=APP_SECRET
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: No signature or personal links should be posted in the answer. This is not a forum.